# Intersections, Tangents to Cubic from Point off the Graph

Tags: calculus, derivatives, cubics

Which lines through the point $(0,3)$ intersect the graph $s=t^3-t$. Need algebraic criterion in terms of coefficients of the equation of the line. Can intersect 3 times, 2 times, 1 time, or never?

$$s=t^3-t$$

Factored form of $s$ is:
$$s=t(t+1)(t-1)$$

Derivative of $s$ is:
$$s'=3t^2-1$$

Then I use the point-slope formula with the given coordinates, where $m$ is the slope:

$$s-3=m(t-0)$$
$$s=mt+3$$

The problem states up to 3 times, so I think the equation will be in the following form:
$$At^3+Bt^2+Ct+D=0$$

Then, I substitute the $s'$ into the point-slope formula line:
$$s=(3t^2-1)t+3$$
$$s=3t^3-t+3$$

I graphed $s=t^3-t$ and $s=3t^3-t+3$ on the same graph and seem to intersect at only one point but am unsure if they intersect out to infinity? Is this the correct method?

Comment: I don't understand where the equation $At^3+Bt^2+Ct+D=0$ comes from. What is it supposed to represent? Its graph would be another cubic. But you're looking for lines, whose equations have to be linear functions. In fact, you've already found a certain form for these lines' equations as $s=mt+3$; now you need to figure out which values of $m$ give you a desired number of intersections.

Comment: Intersection means the line crosses the graph.  This is where I am confused.

Comment: So you're looking for the intersection points of two graphs. What do we often do to find them? For example, what would you do to find the points where the graphs of the functions $y=x^2$ and $y=2x$ intersect?

Answer (score 1):

Since every cubic polynomial has at least one real root, the graph of a cubic polynomial intersects every line in the plane at least once, including vertical lines.

Given $s(t)=t^3-t$ and a line $y=mt+3$, the line will intersect the graph of $S$ twice only at a point where it is tangent to the curve.

The slope of the tangent line to the curve at the point $(t_0,s_0)$ is $m_0=3t_0^2-1$, so the line containing $(0,3)$ which is tangent to the curve will satisfy the point-slope equation of a line

$$ s_0-3=(3t_0^2-1)(t_0-0) $$

And since $s_0=t_0^3-t_0$ this simplifies to
$$2t_0^3=-3$$

So the slope $m_0$ which gives the line intersecting the curve only twice is the line with slope

$$ m_0=3(3/2)^{2/3}-1 $$

Lines through $(0,3)$ having slopes less than $m_0$ (and the vertical line) will intersect the curve only once. Lines through $(0,3)$ having slopes greater than $m_0$ will intersect the curve three times.

[image: Tangent Line]

Comment: I found t = -3/2 but then realized the power of two will alway make positive, so can drop the negative sign?  Works on the graph too?  Cool inference.

Comment: Yes, $t_0=(-3/2)^{1/3}$ .

Answer (score 0):

The slope of a tangent at the point
(t,s(t)) is s'(t) = 3t$^2$ - 1.

The slope of a line from
(t,s(t)) to (0,3) is m = (s(t) - 3)/t.

Set m = s'(t) and solve for t.